# Selecting a form based on a users drop down choice

Tags: php, css, forms, select, dynamic

I am trying to select a form depending on the choice a user makes from a dropdown.

The value of each select is dynamic as shown:

```
<?php
$select="<option value='$id'>" . $number . " " . $title . " " . $ptitle . " " . $stitle . ", Issue " . $issue . "</option>";

    echo $select;
 ?>
```

My questions are:

1. How it is possible to hide the forms until the user selects a relevant 
   option? Current CSS:

> *#$id {* 
>   *visibility:hidden;* 
>       *}*

2. How is it possible to select a form depending on the dropdown choice?

The end goal of this will be to allow a user to write info to a db depending on their selection.

Comment: As PHP is server side, you would need to send another request to show the available form. If you want to dynamically hide and show forms, you'll need to use a client side programming language like JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

With a server side language you cannot interact with the interface because they aren't event oriented. Use instead a client side language like JavaScript, you can use this easy example:

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").addEventListener("change", hide);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bamrLty0/

Comment: i am using dynamic variables, not set ones for the option value